# jQuery Chosen select option triggers link with lower z index when selected on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad

I am using jQuery Chosen plugin to style select box #foo. I have a block level link (#bar) which is positioned just below #foo and which has a lower (0) z index. #foo 's options have a z-index of 1010.

On my ipad mini, when I select an option from #foo, the link (#bar) is triggered. I have no issues on an android tablet, and I am not having any problems on any non-touch browser. Just iPad

Here is my code:

```
<select id="foo">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>foo</option>
</select>

<a href="http:www.stackoverflow.com" id="bar">GO!</a>
```

and the CSS

```
#foo {width:300px;}

#bar {display:block; width:400px; height:100px; color:#FFF; text-align:center; font-size:30px; background:#FF0000; line-height:90px; z-index:0;}
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/356xX/4/) is my fiddle. The css for jQuery chosen is in the fiddle's external resources.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple solution is to listen to the touchend event and stop the propagation. Here is with jQuery :

```
$('.chosen-container .chosen-results').on('touchend', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This has now been fixed on the latest release for the plugin:
https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/commit/1e0422efae5be212acfc17bd40361e143ef40847